# Pass option_for_select value as a parameter in link_to in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_tag form_submit_path do |f| %>

<%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
  [["Select Report Type", 0],
  ["Report 1", 1],
  ["Report 1", 1],
  ]), id: "report_selection")) %>

<%= link_to 'Generate Report', 
              NOT_form_submit_path, 
              report_id: report_selection,
              id: 'generate_report_link', 
              class: 'btn btn-small btn-primary', 
                remote: true%>
```

I have a dropdown inside a form as shown above. I also have a `link_to` as shown above which does NOT call the form submit path but a different path instead. Now, I would like to pass the dropdown selection value as a parameter  (named `report_id`) in my link_to. I am not sure how to do that.

I tried using `report_id: report_selection` as shown above and also `report_id: report_id` but neither of them get passed to my controller (the value comes up as nil in my controller in either case).

How can I pass the parameter in my link_to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the explanation in commented line, this could be done with more short lines of code, but i just explained it step by step.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //$('#report_selection').change(function(){
  $('#report_selection').on('change', function(){
    // get selected value from report_id options
    var selected_val = $(this).val(); 
    // get current path of link
    var link_url = $('#generate_report_link')[0].pathname
    // append selected value in link path and define it as new link
    var new_link_url = link_url + "?report_id=" + selected_val;
    // set new path or link
    $('#generate_report_link').attr('href', new_link_url);
  })
</script>
```

Change link as-

```
<%= link_to 'Generate Report', 
              NOT_form_submit_path,
              id: 'generate_report_link', 
              class: 'btn btn-small btn-primary', 
                remote: true%>
```

Comment: Is there no way to pass the parameter inside the link_to call?

Comment: @Biju I didn't get it by `pass the parameter inside the link_to call? ` can you explain it.

Comment: If you have a look at the `link_to` call I have given above, I have passed a parameter in it (`report_id: report_selection`). Lot of blogs suggest this is the way to pass parameter inside link_to. But it doesn't work for me (maybe because I pass a select_tag value instead of a simple variable?)

Comment: @Biju I'm not sure about that, but one thing sure is that there is no `report_selection ` local variable exists, so on passing it you will always get nil in controller of `params[:report_id]`.

Comment: thanks for the reply - but `id: "report_selection"` has been defined in the dropdown - so I believe report_selection would be the id of the control and hence should have the value?

Comment: @Biju I don't think this would work unless you will get value of `report_selection` using javascript stuffs.

Comment: thanks @gabbar - I tried your solution. For some reason, the javascript function does not get called. I tried adding an `alert` call inside and it never gets invoked. I have a few other javascript functions which get called just fine. I tried both `$('#report_selection').on(change, function(){` and `$('#report_id').on(change, function(){` - neither seem to work!

Comment: @Biju can you make sure that select_tag  has id `report_selection ` by inspecting element. another thing you can try this `$('#report_selection').on('change', function(){...})` or `$('#report_selection').change( function(){...})` ?

Comment: the edited answer worked for me! Thanks much! Just 1 more question pls? I was earlier reading the parameter in my controller like this - `report_option = params[:report_id]` - this was working fine earlier. But now, I get this value when I print `report_option` - `5?report_id=1`. Not sure where the `5` came from. How do I read this parameter value now (by just taking the last character from the params?)?

Comment: @Biju Not sure what are you asking, as i have given the answer, you will always still get `report_id` in params has at controller. so you can get its value as `params[: report_id]`. actually  `report_id` has been appended in url.so to get `report_option` will be same as before.

Comment: I have worked around this issue. I just have one last issue. If the dropdown value is changed say 5 times, the selection gets appended to the previous URL everytime - so the final URL has 5 parameters in it (like `forecast/show?report_id=1?report_id=2?report_id=3?report_id=4?report_id=5`). Is there a way to avoid this please?

Comment: @Biju HI, sorry for late reply you can fetch only `path` on change event instead of `href` so use this `var link_url = $('#generate_report_link')[0].pathname` instead of `var link_url = $('#generate_report_link').attr('href')`.